# Python virtualenvwrapper and ZSH prompt

Tags: zsh, python, virtualenv

I am using archlinux with zsh and python

```
simha@gauranga ~ % echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/zsh

simha@gauranga ~ % python3 --version
Python 3.5.1
```

my .zshrc is

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
source /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Once i open a new terminal

I could create a new virtualenv in the following way. (simha is the home folder name and gauranga is the computer name)

```
simha@gauranga ~ % mkvirtualenv new2
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/simha/.virtualenvs/new3/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /home/simha/.virtualenvs/new3/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/simha/.virtualenvs/new3/bin/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/simha/.virtualenvs/new3/bin/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/simha/.virtualenvs/new3/bin/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/simha/.virtualenvs/new3/bin/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/simha/.virtualenvs/new3/bin/get_env_details
```

Now i am entering the virtualenv

```
simha@gauranga ~ % workon new3
simha@gauranga ~ %
```

if we see above there is no change in the prompt to shown which env in am in.

I have followed the http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tips.html for zsh prompt still its not working

the following are the postactivate and postdeactivate files

```
simha@gauranga ~ % tail -f .virtualenvs/postactivate .virtualenvs/postdeactivate
==> .virtualenvs/postactivate <==
PS1="$_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1"
_OLD_RPROMPT="$RPROMPT"
RPROMPT="%{${fg_bold[white]}%}(env: %{${fg[green]}%}`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`%{${fg_bold[white]}%})%{${reset_color}%} $RPROMPT"

==> .virtualenvs/postdeactivate <==
RPROMPT="$_OLD_RPROMPT"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the **grml** zsh config, which is the default configuration for ArchLinux, then you'll need to do some theme configuration in your **~/.zshrc** file.

Grml's current setup uses prompt themes, which use the prompt variable PS1. PS1 is used by virtualenv to display the current active virtualenvironment. If virtualenv changes the PS1 variable, the theme code will just change it back to the value of the current theme.

**Adding:**

> source /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
>   export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
>   function virtual_env_prompt () {
>   REPLY=${VIRTUAL_ENV+(${VIRTUAL_ENV:t}) }
>   }
>   grml_theme_add_token virtual-env -f virtual_env_prompt '%F{magenta}' '%f'
>   zstyle ':prompt:grml:left:setup' items rc virtual-env change-root user at host path vcs percent

To your **.zshrc** file should do the trick.

**Source of wording and answer:**
http://bewatermyfriend.org/p/2013/003/

Edits:
wording and spelling